# How to add distinct values form one list of hash map to another list of hash map

Tags: java, list, hashmap

Could someone help me out in getting the correct list with no duplicates.

I have a list of hash map say "HashMap map" whose size is 4.
The key value pair is something similar to the below

```
("uri_path","/shophome/index")
("AvgResp","30.00")
("count", "3");
("status","200");
```

I want to create another List of Hashmap which  contains single entry for "uri_path" and the average and count calculated accordingly. This is what i am trying out.Ideally the size of the new list should be lesser than the original .Can someone help understand were it is going wrong

```
HashMap<String, String> processedMap = null;
        List<HashMap<String, String>> artProcessedEvents=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : artEvents) {// list that contains the values
            processedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            String uri_path= map.get("uri_path");
            Double art = Double.parseDouble(map.get("avgRespT"));   
            count =Integer.parseInt(map.get("count"));



            if (processedMap.containsValue(uri_path)){

                Double artFromMap = Double.parseDouble(processedMap.get("avgRespT"));
                int countFromMap =Integer.parseInt(processedMap.get("count"));
                count = count+countFromMap;
                art = ((art*count) + (artFromMap*countFromMap))/count;

            }

            processedMap.put("uri_path",uri_path);
            processedMap.put("avgRespT",String.valueOf(art));
            processedMap.put("count", String.valueOf(count));
            artProcessedEvents.add(processedMap);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you know that something is wrong?

Comment: This line: `if (processedMap.containsValue(uri_path)){` doesent make sense as the map will always be empty. You just created it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> artEvents = ...;

//this map stores all of the result maps (one map per uri_path, uri_path is the key in this uniqueUriMap, map itself being a value).
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> uniqueUriMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>(); 

for (HashMap<String, String> mapBeingProcessed : artEvents) 
{
    String uri_path = mapBeingProcessed.get("uri_path");
    Double art = Double.parseDouble(mapBeingProcessed.get("avgRespT"));   
    Integer count =Integer.parseInt(mapBeingProcessed.get("count"));

    if (uniqueUriMap.containsKey(uri_path)) 
    {
        Double artFromMap = Double.parseDouble(uniqueUriMap.get(uri_path).get("avgRespT"));
        int countFromMap = Integer.parseInt(uniqueUriMap.get(uri_path).get("count"));
        count = count + countFromMap;
        art = ((art * count) + (artFromMap * countFromMap)) / count;
    }

    HashMap<String, String> newUriMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    newUriMap.put("uri_path",uri_path);
    newUriMap.put("avgRespT",String.valueOf(art));
    newUriMap.put("count", String.valueOf(count));
    uniqueUriMap.put(uri_path, newUriMap);
}
//result list.
List<HashMap<String, String>> artProcessedEvents=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
artProcessedEvents.addAll(uniqueUriMap.values());
```

The problem was with storing the temp values. This:

```
if (processedMap.containsValue(uri_path))
```

always returned false as you initialized processedMap inside the loop.

Comment: I got your point ,Let me try it out and confirm Thanks for the code snippet

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.
Sorry for the minimal description but this list-map-map stuff is quite complicated to describe in comment. I let the code speak for itself ;)

Comment: I tried similar way you mentioned but its is not entering the condition if (uniqueUriMap.containsValue(uri_path)) My requirement is if i get another entry with same uri_path i should find the average of both depending on the count . Eg if the Initial list contains only 2 entries                                  ("uri_path","/shophome/index")
("AvgResp","30.00")
("count", "3");
("status","200");                                                                                       ;

Comment: ("uri_path","/shophome/index")
("AvgResp","10.00")
("count", "1");
("status","400") Then my final list should contain only ("uri_path","/shophome/index")
("AvgResp","25.00")
("count", "4");

Comment: Hey i got it corrected . The condition should be .containsKey instead of .containsValue .Thanks a lot for your suggestions It worked :)

Comment: Also need to remove the " else "

Comment: @IvySaju I've edited it as you suggested. Sorry for the mixing the key-value part. As for else i thought that in the if statement the values of the map are updated, but they are clearly not. That's why the else is neaded to substitute the old values with new ones. Else could stay if in the if there was something like this:

`uniqueUriMap.get(uri_path).put("count", String.valueOf(count + countFromMap);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem,

```
if (processedMap.containsValue(uri_path)){

    Double artFromMap = Double.parseDouble(processedMap.get("avgRespT"));
    int countFromMap =Integer.parseInt(processedMap.get("count"));
    count = count+countFromMap;
    art = ((art*count) + (artFromMap*countFromMap))/count;

}
```

You have to get the value from the "map" (for loop variable) and manipulate it. And also processedMap will be empty for every run and that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing yourself a lot here but this would help.

In order to remove duplicates and update your parameters you would need to change processedmap from a simple string->string hashmap to a string->Hashmap i.e as shown below.Following that you would need to add it to the list via an iterator.

```
 HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> processedMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> artProcessedEvents=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : artEvents) {// list that contains the values


            String uri_path= map.get("uri_path");
            Double art = Double.parseDouble(map.get("avgRespT"));   
            count =Integer.parseInt(map.get("count"));



            if (processedMap.containsValue(uri_path)){

                Double artFromMap = Double.parseDouble(processedMap.get("avgRespT"));
                int countFromMap =Integer.parseInt(processedMap.get("count"));
                count = count+countFromMap;
                art = ((art*count) + (artFromMap*countFromMap))/count;

            }
           //Create a new Hashmap 
             HashMap<String, String> updatedMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
            updatedMap.put("uri_path",uri_path);
            updatedMap.put("avgRespT",String.valueOf(art));
            updatedMap.put("count", String.valueOf(count));
            processedMap.put(uri_path,updateMap);

            }
            //Iterate and add elements to the list
              for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : processedMap.entrySet())
             {
               artProcessedEvents.add(entry.getValue());
             }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michal and others your suggestions

The below code solved my issues

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> artEvents =new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
//this map stores all of the result maps (one map per uri_path, uri_path is the key in this uniqueUriMap, map itself being a value).
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> uniqueUriMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>(); 

for (HashMap<String, String> mapBeingProcessed : artEvents) 
{
    String uri_path = mapBeingProcessed.get("uri_path");
    Double art = Double.parseDouble(mapBeingProcessed.get("avgRespT"));   
    Integer count =Integer.parseInt(mapBeingProcessed.get("count"));

    if (uniqueUriMap.containsKey(uri_path)) 
    {
        Double artFromMap = Double.parseDouble(uniqueUriMap.get(uri_path).get("avgRespT"));
        int countFromMap =Integer.parseInt(uniqueUriMap.get(uri_path).get("count"));
        count = count + countFromMap;
        art = ((art * count) + (artFromMap * countFromMap)) / count;
    }

        HashMap<String, String> newUriMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        newUriMap.put("uri_path",uri_path);
        newUriMap.put("avgRespT",String.valueOf(art));
        newUriMap.put("count", String.valueOf(count));
        uniqueUriMap.put(uri_path, newUriMap);

}
//result list.
List<HashMap<String, String>> artProcessedEvents=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
artProcessedEvents.addAll(uniqueUriMap.values());
```